# Vim, :DiffSave function breaks vim window

Tags: bash, shell, vim

Using vim: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32), Huge version without GUI

version reports this:

```
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
```

Using http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Diff_current_buffer_and_the_original_file :DiffSaved completely breaks my vim window. It breaks me out to shell, then I have to do `fg` twice before it takes me back into the vim (sometimes the terminal window just closes). The window at first looks ok, but when I try and type the terminal prompt appears in the top window and overwrites the vim window. It seems like vim displays the diffed file, but then crashes and never clears the screen.

Possibly related: when I run a shell command with `:! ...` the vim window will go into background and the command will run, but I'm not always prompted with the `Press enter to continue` which will bring me back into vim automatically. I have to do `fg` to get back into the prompt. It seems like something similar is happening here.

This behavior is new, it did work at one point. I'm not sure what I changed to break it, but I would like to get the capability to use that function and shell commands back.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd guess you have some quirky stuff in your shell initialization (e.g. `.bashrc`) that does this.

Comment: Building on Ingo's comment, I'd try removing the `.bashrc`/`.cshrs`/`.profile`, etc, one file each time, starting a new shell and checking if the problem still happens, until the culprit file is found. Once it is, restore it, then comment the first half, and check if the problem exists. If it is gone, then the problem is in the first half, thus comment the first quarter -- follow this procedure until you find the line that causes the problem. You could also follow this procedure with your `.vimrc`.